# XBox Api for games achievements

Tags: java, android, api, xbox

Does anyone kn ow where can I get an api where i can get all the achievements for a specific game? Not for a specific gamertag. I need all achievements for the xbox ones games.

I have don't some scrapping but I want to take my app to the next level and i don't want to rely on the scrapping websites.

Comment: There's not one that I know of. There used to be an API (that's how MyGamerCard.net worked) but it's since been discontinued by Microsoft. As far as I know, big sites like TrueAchievements just scrape Xbox.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You looked at using http://xboxapi.com ?

Something similar to what your after - http://xbonx.com